# How to separate unique values into sheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel, email, worksheet-function, sorting, microsoft-excel-2016

I have an excel file with around 10.000 leads, categorized with Name, **Email, Company name, Position, City, CheckedEmailAddress, Mail server Country Code,**
last one **Mail server Country Code**, there are 11 different Mail server Country Code, I need to take all 11 by 11 leads from all of them, that means 1 sheet 11 leads from 11 different mail servers, so, all sheets 11 leads from different Mail servers country code

Hope you understand me! Every sheet should have unique values from mail server category.

I started by removing duplicates and again and again but this process takes like forever.

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand. Are you able to provide a couple of pictures with an example of how it is now and what you want it to be? Even if you just make these up, it may help us :)

Comment: @Dave please check this video I just made, https://streamable.com/gjpr0

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand what you are trying to do, but I think what I would do is add a new column, then filter the country column and add 1, 2, 3.... to the new column. Repeat for each country. Then you can filter the new column for values "1", "2"... and copy and past each to a new sheet.
Not the most efficient way of solving what I think is your problem but it will work, assuming I understood your goal.

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose thank you, but that will take time more than I'm doing right now, anyway thank you,

I need something like macros script or something like that

Answer (score 0):

```
H1:  Count of MSCC
H2:  =COUNTIF($G$2:G2,G2)
```

Select `H2` and fill down to the bottom. This will result in appropriate numbering for filtering.

Then Filter on each value and copy (visible cells) / Paste (do NOT cut or delete, or the numbering will change) to the new worksheet.

Or you can use the Advanced Filter selecting the option to paste results to a different location.

Or you could record a macro while doing the above, and then edit the macro to change the selection and destination criteria.

Comment: I don't understand what are you saying but I put down below an excel file if you can try if that works, I really appreciate that.

https://www.sendspace.com/file/g7mkft

Comment: @EdinNeziri What exactly is it that you don't understand? My first suggestion has you adding formula to a worksheet; filling it into a range, and then using a filter. If your knowledge of excel has not progressed to this level, you may be best off hiring a consultant for this task, and perhaps perusing some basic Excel teaching tutorials or books for the future.

Comment: thank you for your answer, please if you can send me an excel with that formula I will understand it perfectly, thank you

Comment: @EdinNeziri Entering the formula on your Excel worksheet is your responsibility.  I have provided you with the formula and a suggested cell address. Entering a formula in a cell is a very basic Excel task.  Again, if you are unable to do this, you will need to hire someone, or perhaps find a site that will do your work for free.

Comment: thank you, this is a demo I did what I'm trying to do, in this video a go with Domina category to filter unique, can you confirm that with your code I can do this faster,

Demo >> https://streamable.com/r50pq

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Given the difficulty you are having in implementing my suggestions, I suggest you keep on with what you are doing. Yes, if you were able to implement them correctly, and adapt them to your process, and perhaps even record a VBA macro, you could speed up your process considerably. Whether it is worthwhile for you to spend the time and effort to get to that point is a question only you can answer.  But I won't be able to help you further with this process.